# How can achieve a similar appearance using the gradient tool on illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, gradient

[image: Example of what I'd like to achieve.]
I already know how to create the spacing using the gradient tool. However the center image seems integrated with the spacing and not just sitting in the background.

Comment: Looks like to me as if it's just sitting in the background.

Answer (score 5):

There's no gradient anywhere in that image.

It is merely a line pattern. You can achieve this by drawing 3 lines of varying thickness.

[image]

Select all 3 and choose `Object > Blend > Make`

[image]

You may need to then choose `Object > Blend > Blend Options` to adjust the blend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have better luck with the Blend tool.

It also appears as if the center image has light lines of a constant width and spacing that match up with the gradient lines.